# How do I export a JAR file from a java project on Codenvy?

Tags: codenvy

I probably am missing something simple. 
I can build the file and run it, but I need a graphical display. I can't connect via vnc at work.

So I need to export the JAR and run it locally. 
How do I export a JAR file from a java project on Codenvy?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

It's right were it's supposed to be.
It is in the target folder.

Like I said I was missing something simple.